# Gulp-rev: isn't working at the first time, but after it

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm having an error, but don't know why it happens. In the following code I build css files. The task "build-single-styles" (in runSequence) builds temporary css-files. The second task concatenates every css file with two other files and writes them in the same folder one level deeper, into "/concat".

The last function should build a json-file

```
{
  "base.css": "base-zt121112fd.css,
  ...
}
```

which holds key-value pairs, that I can integrate the hashed css-files into the different templates. It's fired when all css-files are written into the "/concat"-folder.

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');

//run single tasks in a row
gulp.task('build-styles', function(){
  runSequence('build-single-styles', 'concat-styles');
});

//build styles
gulp.task('build-single-styles', function() {
  return gulp.src(allStyles)
    .pipe($.plumber({ errorHandler: function (error) {}}))
    .pipe($.rubySass({
        style: sassStyle,
        compass: true,
        noCache: true
    }))
    .pipe(isProduction ? $.combineMediaQueries({ log: true }) : _.noop())
    .pipe(isProduction ? $.minifyCss({ keepSpecialComments: 1 }) : _.noop())
    .pipe($.plumber.stop())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.destTemp))
    .pipe($.size({
        showFiles: true
    }))
});

//concat each css with 2 others
gulp.task('concat-styles', function(){
  var files = fs.readdirSync(paths.styles.destTemp);
  var index = files.indexOf('slider.css');

  if(index > -1) files.splice(index, 1);

  var autosuggest = paths.styles.srcBase + '/autosuggest_inquisitor.css';

  for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    gulp.src([paths.styles.destTemp + '/' + files[i], autosuggest, paths.styles.destTemp + '/slider.css'])
        .pipe($.concat({path: files[i], cwd: ''}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.destTemp + '/concat'));

    if(i == files.length - 1) buildManifest();
}
});

function buildManifest(){
  gulp.src([paths.styles.destTemp + '/concat/*.css', !paths.styles.destTemp + '/concat/slider.css'])
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest))
    .pipe(rev.manifest({ base: styleLinkup, path: 'styles-linkup.json' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(styleLinkup));
}
```

When i run "gulp build-styles" the first time the function "buildManifest" fires correct, but nothing is written, as if it doesn't find the src-folder. If I run it twice it works. The rev'd files are written and so the json-file. Any assumptions?

Greetings,
Lars

**Edit 1:** Making a task out of the function "buildManifest" and run it alone after building the final css-files also works. But it's not working when putting the task into the sequence.

**Edit 2:** I tried sth. else inside the buildManifest function:

```
var concatFiles = fs.readdirSync(paths.styles.destTemp + '/concat');
console.log(concatFiles);
```

Now I get an error on "fs.readdirSync(paths.styles.destTemp + '/concat');" and it says the following:

Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory './web/assets/css/temp/concat'.

Seems like the folder which I create before isn't detected right after its creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pipe` is running things asynchronously so in this block your call to `buildManifest` will execute before the `concat` happens:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    gulp.src([paths.styles.destTemp + '/' + files[i], autosuggest, paths.styles.destTemp + '/slider.css'])
        .pipe($.concat({path: files[i], cwd: ''}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.destTemp + '/concat'));

    if(i == files.length) buildManifest();
```

Try making `buildManifest` it's own task and adding it to your `runSequence`

Comment: ah i see.  your concat-styles needs to have a callback or a return value.  see https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support

Comment: I saw that before and thought about it in the subway. ^^ I'm close to a solution.

Comment: Thanks, to made me think about it again. I have the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without generating single streams and merge them all together the last task (building the manifest) fires to early.

**So I made an own task out of the manifest again, create single streams and merge them. On this way it works.**

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('build-styles', function(){
  runSequence('build-single-styles', 'concat-styles', 'build-manifest');
});

gulp.task('build-single-styles', function() {
  return gulp.src(allStyles)
    .pipe($.plumber({ errorHandler: function (error) {}}))
    .pipe($.rubySass({
        style: sassStyle,
        compass: true,
        noCache: true
    }))
    .pipe(isProduction ? $.combineMediaQueries({ log: true }) : _.noop())
    .pipe(isProduction ? $.minifyCss({ keepSpecialComments: 1 }) : _.noop())
    .pipe($.plumber.stop())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.destTemp))
    .pipe($.size({
        showFiles: true
    }))
});

gulp.task('concat-styles', function(done){
  var files = fs.readdirSync(paths.styles.destTemp),
      index = files.indexOf('slider.css'),
      autosuggest = paths.styles.srcBase + '/autosuggest_inquisitor.css',
      slider = paths.styles.destTemp + '/slider.css',
      streams = [];

  if (index > -1) files.splice(index, 1);

  for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    streams.push(gulp.src([paths.styles.destTemp + '/' + files[i], autosuggest, slider])
        .pipe($.concat({path: files[i], cwd: ''}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.destTemp + '/concat')));
  }
  return merge(streams);
});

gulp.task('build-manifest', function() {
  gulp.src([paths.styles.destTemp + '/concat/*.css', !paths.styles.destTemp + '/concat/slider.css'])
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest))
    .pipe(rev.manifest({ base: styleLinkup, path: 'styles-linkup.json' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(styleLinkup));
});
```